# Icon on Files -> Devices does not disappear

Tags: pantheon-files

I have probably not removed a usb stick properly and as a consequence I have an icon on Files which does not disappear. Have run umount (now it shows as an empty folder), deleted the folder from the /media folder and it still shows in Files (if I click it will still show as empty folder). How can I remove it? Many thanks

Comment: I assume you've tried closing and reopening Files? Is the USB stick still showing as a device in the sidebar?  If so try ejecting it. If this does not work try logging out and back in.  Restarting should fix it as a last resort.

Comment: Have closed/reopened Files, rebooted the computer, reinstalled Files, did umount the device, the device seems indestructible!

Comment: Have you tried this? In the “about” window for elementary OS 0.4, there’s a small button here to “Restore Default Settings”, if you messed with some system or interface settings and would like to go back to the default ones, just click this button.

Comment: Thanks I tried but didn't help. Have finally solved it: using gparted, removed it by deleting the partition. Not too sure what that means, if I had actually created a new partition without realizing

Comment: A permanent partition should not have been created (restarting the computer should have cleared it).  If it was then it is unlikely that Files was the culprit.  It just shows whatever volumes are reported by the system VolumeMonitor.